# Limiting SSH Tunnel users maxlogins

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, tunnel

I've created a bunch of users on my Ubuntu VPS to do just SSH tunneling using this command: (taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174376/how-to-create-a-user-with-the-least-privileges-permissions-but-enough-to-do-ssh))

`sudo adduser someuser --shell=/bin/false --no-create-home`

which works fine as expected. These users don't get shell access and can just use the tunneling feature. I need to limit these users per username/maxlogin. I want each user to be able to use it on only one login session. (so that the same account doesn't get used twice)

I've tried editing `/etc/security/limits.conf`

`someuser hard maxlogins 1`

but it doesn't work. I've tried that for normal users (with shell access permissions) and it does work. So it only doesn't work on my limited users. Running `who` also doesn't show online SSH tunneling users.

Is it possible to limit these type of users per logins?

Comment: Try using `-` instead of `hard` like `someuser - maxlogins 1`. It should work as long as you have sshd using PAM and pam_limits configured for the ssh login path. Otherwise check some options in the other answers here https://serverfault.com/a/245348/411612

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Thanks for the answer. With `-` it didn't work either but the link you provided gave me the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Thanks for your response. My message was deleted since I didn't have enough reputation to ask my question "as a comment"! I don't know if ever stackexchange is gonna fix it's rules to support comments without reputation.

Anyway, I also found a way to fix the problem by running some bash: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347714/conditionally-stop-interactive-and-non-interactive-ssh-login-and-give-error-mess

The main idea is to run a script for every sshd login to check certain condition (here number of past active sshd). Hence, first we need to save our script in a file, say, /root/checkConnections.

```
#! /bin/bash

limit=$1
c=$(pgrep -xcu $PAM_USER sshd)
if [[ $c -ge "$limit" ]]; then 
    echo "Max $limit ssh connections allowed, but you have $c."
    exit 1
fi
```

Don't forget to make it executable. Now, you run this script at every sshd session by adding this in /etc/pam.d/sshd:

```
session required pam_exec.so stdout /root/checkConnections 5
```

In short, at every session pam_exec.so run the script and if the limit (here 5) violated it fails. Instead of stdout, one can use a log file, by replacing stdout with log=file.log, to log output messages. Remember this will also set limit on root too. So, in case you want to have more complex instructions you have to change checkConnections as desired.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.